# Android cardElevation Dynamically change

Tags: android, android-layout, android-cardview

How to pragmatically increase the shadow of cardview in android on tap on it ? 
I am able to change the shadow through the xml by using **card_view:cardElevation** But I want to increase the shadow of this on any touch or click event.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/CardView.html#setCardElevation(float)

Answer (score 0):

`CardView` has a method `setCardElevation(float)`  and `setMaxCardElevation(float)` a think they can help you for your case ( set card elevation programatically). Hope to help!